# Which format is tidy?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

Let's say I have a dataset of ACT test scores. Each "observation" is a student's results from taking the ACT. The ACT has five subjects: reading, English, math, science, and writing (plus a composite score). Each test subject has a scale score, a national percentile rank, and a college readiness indicator (`Y` or `N`).

My question is (and always seems to be since I work a lot with assessment data), which format is "tidy"?

- where each row is a unique student test + subject combination with a `subject` column and then `scaleScore`, `percentile`, and `readiness` columns for each value.
- where each row is a unique student test with all the subjects and their respective values listed out in separate columns.
- Or where I have something like the first option but put into six tables one for each subject with a key to join on?

I've been working in SQL + Excel for a while, but I want to expand my EDA skills in R. Any help would be much appreciated! The key focus is on subsequent visualization with `ggplot`. I'm guessing the answer may just be "it depends" with a willingness to `gather` and `spread` for different plotting purposes.

Comment: [Here's the canonical paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf), but it does depend. If you were trying to fit Science scores on Math and Reading scores, your data would have to be in wide form. If you were trying to plot score densities by subject in ggplot, it would need to be in long form.

Comment: In many cases, having data TOO tidy can be a real hindrance, particularly if you'd like to run calculations across rows. Knowing how to reshape data is more important than being wedded to a single format. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns being student, test, subject, scaleScore, percentile, readiness.

Student and test variables would identify each observation.

Subject is a variable. Reading, English, math, etc. are *values* of the subject variable. This is essentially the heart of the tidy approach, which tends to be deep, not wide, and lends itself to joining, grouping, plotting, and so forth.

OR to make it really tidy, score and scoreType are variables, and their respective values are included as observations.

Either way, in one table the student and test would be repeated on multiple rows. But this serves to illustrate the tidy perspective. Clearly, normalized tables are a worthy consideration, in terms of the big picture.